# Object inventory class including a logger class overwrites dictionary entries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, object, logging

I found this strange behaviour of Python 3.7.2 (I have not tried other versions). I created the following case scenario and in the hope to understand what is happening better.

I want to write a Object Inventory class including a logger class that logs the current inventory at a counter (e.g. every day). Then I want to use the logger class to retrieve the inventory on a certain day.

Here is the code:

```
class Obj():
    def __init__(self, parameter):
        self.par = parameter


class ObjInventory():
    def __init__(self, object_list):
        self.list_of_objects = object_list
        self.counter = 0
        self.logger = InventoryLogger()

    def increase_counter(self):
        self.logger.add_list_at_counter(self.counter, self.list_of_objects)
        self.counter += 1


class InventoryLogger():
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict_of_positions = {}

    def add_list_at_counter(self, counter, object_list):
        self.dict_of_positions[counter] = object_list

    def print_object_inventory_on_count(self, counter):
         object_list = self.dict_of_positions[counter]
         list_of_parameters = [object.par for object in object_list]
         print(list_of_parameters)


Inventory = ObjInventory([])

first_list_of_objects = [Obj(1), Obj(2), Obj(3)]
Inventory.list_of_objects += first_list_of_objects
Inventory.increase_counter()
Inventory.logger.print_object_inventory_on_count(0)

second_list_of_objects = [Obj(4), Obj(5), Obj(6)]
Inventory.list_of_objects += second_list_of_objects
Inventory.increase_counter()
Inventory.logger.print_object_inventory_on_count(1)

del Inventory.list_of_objects[2:4]
Inventory.increase_counter()
Inventory.logger.print_object_inventory_on_count(2)

Inventory.logger.print_object_inventory_on_count(0)
Inventory.logger.print_object_inventory_on_count(1)
Inventory.logger.print_object_inventory_on_count(2)
```

The expected outcome would be this:

```
[1, 2, 3] #---> first 3 objects

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] #---> first 3 objects and additional 3 objects

[1, 2, 5, 6] #---> list without removed objects

[1, 2, 3] #reiteration

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

[1, 2, 5, 6]
```

**BUT** what I get instead is this:

```
[1, 2, 3]

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

[1, 2, 5, 6]

[1, 2, 5, 6]

[1, 2, 5, 6]

[1, 2, 5, 6]
```

So the logger print works **only after it is called directly**. If I call the logger function at a later step, **all** dictionary entries become equal to the last entry.

I have found a workaround by amending the add_list_at_counter function the following way, which results in the desired code response:

```
def add_list_at_counter(self, counter, object_list):
    self.dict_of_positions[counter] = []
    self.dict_of_positions[counter] += object_list
```

Especially the workaround (that I found after hours trying to understand why the code is not working) leaves me confused. Any ideas why the second code is working and the first is not? Or is it some kind of bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is caused by the fact that many of the lists that are the values in the dictionary in your logger are in fact references to the same `list_of_objects`.

Compare it to this code:

```
x = [1,2,3]      # x refers to a list
y = x            # y is another reference to the same list
x.append(4)      # modify the list through x
print(y)         # prints [1, 2, 3, 4], even though we accessed via y
```

Your code is doing the same thing, but instead of simple variables like `x` and `y`, you're referencing the list through attributes and dictionary values (`Inventory.list_of_objects` and `Inventory.logger.dict_of_positions[counter]` for each `counter` value).

I don't entirely understand what your code is supposed to be doing, but I suspect you can avoid this issue by changing `increase_counter` to create a copy of the `list_of_objects` list using the `list` constructor:

```
def increase_counter(self):
    self.logger.add_list_at_counter(self.counter, list(self.list_of_objects)) # new list
    self.counter += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply.
I see what you mean. I thought I would with every iteration of add_list_at_counter put the current list as a new static list into the dictionary. This also explains why the second code works, because there explicitly a new empty list is created and then populated.

Thanks a lot for the clarification!